# Adding initialisation time code to existing classes without subclassing

Tags: ios, swift, macos, protocols

I have a case where I need to modify all instances of NSView, trivial by adding a couple of lines of code to init() but how can that be done cleanly for all subclasses in Swift?

The case I have in mind:

- I add a custom property to NSView via an extension
- That works fine, but isn't animatable until it's registered as animatable via the layer's addAnimation:forKey: method.

So all I really need to do is ensure that addAnimation:forKey: gets called every time NSView or a subclass gets called.

Things I've considered:

- Somehow doing this in an extension. Problem: extensions can't override functions, and without overriding init() or something like viewDidAppear() the code has to be called manually every time (e.g. with a convenience initialiser).
- Subclass NSView and add the code. Problem: NSButton, Slider and all the rest won't inherit the code, and I have to subclass them all.
- Method swizzling. This should be possible, because obj-c methods are swizzlable and NSView inherits from NSObject.

So far only swizzling seems viable, but I'm reluctant to do this because it's reliant on the APIs staying obj-c friendly, and I don't know how long that will be the case for.

Is there another way?

Comment: Is there a way you can inject your edited class during a precompile step?

Comment: It's possible to make pre-compile changes with "#if os(OSX)" etc. (which helps a lot as I'm doing cross platform stuff), but I can't see it helping with "editing" the class so far. Any pointers would be very welcome!